# How to see what has changed in new helm chart relase

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I would like to see the changes made to the helm chart compared to its previous release - running `helm list` i see there were xx revisions - any way to see differences ? I know about rollback `helm rollback <RELEASE> 0` but just wanted to know what's changed

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On [helm website](https://helm.sh/docs/community/related/) you can find some plugins.
One of them called [helm-diff](https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff), and it can generate diffs between releases.

Here is how to use this plugin:

```
$ helm diff release -h

This command compares the manifests details of a different releases created from the same chart

It can be used to compare the manifests of

 - release1 with release2
    $ helm diff release [flags] release1 release2
   Example:
    $ helm diff release my-prod my-stage
```

[Here is explained how to install the plugin](https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff#install).
TLDR: if you are using helm version > 2.3.x jest run:

```
helm plugin install https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff
```

Let me know it this solves your problem. If you have any further questions I'd be happy to answer them.

Comment: not really what I was looking for - comparing two different release of the same chart, but rather two revisions of the same release

Comment: Well, then use [helm diff revision](https://github.com/databus23/helm-diff#revision). Its the same plugin.

Comment: Please note that you need to have a cluster running for `helm diff revision` to work. Otherwise, you will get `dial tcp ...: connect: connection refused` and the plugin exits